# Choosing the correct title for a paragraph

Tags: meaning-in-context, titles

> I first went to Harrow in the summer term. The school possessed the biggest swimming-bath
>   I had ever seen. It was more like the bend of a river than a bath, and it had two bridges
>   across it. We used to go there for hours at a time, and bask between our dips, eating
>   enormous buns, on the hot asphalt margin. Naturally it was a good joke to come up behind
>   some friend, or even enemy, and push him in. I made quite a habit of this with boys of
>   my own size or less. One day when I had been no more than a month in the school, I saw a
>   boy standing in a meditative posture wrapped in a towel on the very brink. He was no bigger
>   than I was, so I thought him fair game. Coming stealthily behind, I pushed him in, holding on
>   to his towel out of humanity, so that it should not get wet.

The question is choosing the correct title for above paragraph. Of course there is a list to choose from. The key suggests "*Giving Way to Temptation*".

What does this title mean? Why does it best describe the content of the paragraph?

As I looked up in the dictionary, the title can be understood as "failing to resist a negative desire". However, I don't understand what **temptation** in the title refers to. In other words, I can't find the link between the title and the content.

Comment: Is this a  homework assignment?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. What does your research tell you about [temptation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/temptation) and [giving way](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/give-way)? (See 1.2 of *give way*) Please **show your research,** [add it into the question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/260937/edit) and say what you remain unclear about.

Comment: @deadrat No. The question is from a test.

Comment: @Andrew Leach♦ Thank you for your comment. I will edit the post as you suggested.

Comment: @munmunxuxu Perhaps you could give the other choices.  There doesn't seem to be much temptation in the tale, just reflexive high spirits.  But the other choices may be (and apparently are) even less apt.  (FWIW, this passage is from Churchill's biography *My Early Life*.)

Comment: When I read this passage, I suspected that its purpose was to introduce the boy who was pushed in. Looking on the internet, I found that this was indeed correct. The truncated paragraph isn't really properly structured to stand on its own. I don't think *Giving Way to Temptation* is a good title, as that is not the theme of the paragraph. The whole thing, including the continuation, could be titled *How I Met Amery*. But that title wouldn't make sense for the truncation.

Answer (score -1):

Yes I will describe you that how come temptation is used here, As you have seen in the paragraph that how author pushes everybody either friends or enemies in the bath, this is the temptation of author '**a desire to do something, especially something wrong or unwise**'. So Author Gives a way to desire to do something unwise. If you go for meaning of temptation you will find this answer.